# How to setup routes for a docker container to reach LDAP server?

Tags: ldap, docker, docker-compose

Here's my setup:

- I have a Node.js docker container that needs to be able to make LDAPS calls to an Active Directory Domain Controller to authenticate users (Domain Controller is NOT in a container).
- This Node.js app container connects to another container for DB

Unfortunately, my request to the domain controller times out.  I have installed a number of tools on the container to help troubleshoot and narrow down where the problem might be.

1. `ldapsearch` hangs and then timesout.
2. I cannot get a correct DNS entry for the domain controller.
3. I attempt to be able to ping the correct IP of the domain controller directly and it doesn't have a route to get there.

There are myriad resources out there that explain *some* of the things I will need to do **at a high level**, but what I am most interested in is a step-by-step guide of how to set that up.

(Development is being done on macOS, but the production environment is on Linux.)

*What are the **specific steps** necessary to setup a docker container to reach an external LAN resource?*

Comment: A quick way (but less secure) is to start your container with `--net=host`, assuming your host can reach the ldap server.

Comment: @jordanm I did that, and it can reach the LDAP server, but now I can't hit the node server from my host machine via localhost or any other known host interface.